# Comma or no comma: "...save for the last digit [,] which is 2."

Tags: grammar, punctuation, commas, clauses, non-restrictive

Comma or no comma: "11112 is a number whose digits are all 1, save for the last digit [,] which is 2.

My sentence is of the following form:

> Comma or no comma: "11112 is a number whose digits are all 1, save for the last digit [?] which is 2.

Does the place with a [?] require the use of a comma, require that there is no comma or a comma is optional? I've read that a non-restrictive clause requires a comma before which but I'm not sure if this is a non-restrictive clause (I just encountered this terminology today) because all examples I can find have the non-restrictive clause in the middle (My car, which is pink, is ugly.). Moreover, I would like to stick to the original sentence with minimal modifications.

Explanations and references will be appreciated!

Comment: You need the comma. (That clause couldn't be more nonessential if it tried. It restates the obvious: 2 is the last digit in 1112.)

Comment: I'd use  "11 112 is a number whose digits are all 1 except for the last digit, which is 2."

Comment: @TinfoilHat Okay, what if it was more along the lines of "I am thinking of a number whose digits are all 1 save for the last digit which is even." Still a comma?

Comment: Yes, still a comma—it's extra information. If you want to really bake it in, try: *I am thinking of a number whose digits are all 1 save for an even final digit.*